# Code viewer with color syntax integrated to the finder preview panel

Tags: finder, software-recommendation, preview, file, text-editor

On Windows there is a [great extension for the preview panel.](https://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/delphi-preview-handler/)

It shows the content of the selected file as if it was opened in a code editor. 
This is integrated into the preview panel (no popup window), without the need to to press a key combination and closing the preview afterward.
This allows to browse the content very fast (pressing the up/down keys).

I'm aware of the existence of [Quick Look plugins](https://github.com/sindresorhus/quick-look-plugins), but as far as I know we still need to press command + Y to access the preview and close it after.
Not very handy to quickly go from file to file...

Does anyone know of an equivalent?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After installing [QLColorCode](https://github.com/n8gray/QLColorCode) you just have to hit the spacebar to get a similar experience.

To cycle through your files in list view use the up- or down-arrow. To open a chosen folder hit the right-arrow and continue cycling through your code files. To close a folder hit the left-arrow. The other view options work similar (e.g to open a folder in icon view you have to hit cmd + right-arrow).

Hit the spacebar once more to close the preview window.

For some source code files you might have to disable the Xcode QuickView plugin.
Check the readme file of QLColorCode to modify the theme and other aspects of syntax highlighting.

Comment: Cheers, that's perfect!